# How to combine duplicate information in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python programming. I am trying to manipulate data from a table. I would like to combine all events on the same day into one entry, while showing all participants, and a description of the event. Please see the attached screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If the event and event description happen on the same day then combine all of the ID's together. If the event description is different create a new row for that data and combine the ID's. To make things more difficult the list of information will continually grow overtime and I will be pulling in more events and adding them to the table I am working off

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yefe.png)

I have no idea if this is possible, I have tried dataframes and gotten close but not exactly what I am looking for. Any information is greatly appreciated

my code

```
import pandas as pd

x1= ['2023-06-20','2023-06-20','2023-06-20','2023-06-20','2023-06-20',
    '2023-06-23','2023-06-23','2023-06-23','2023-06-23','2023-06-23']
x2= ['1','2','3,'4','5','1','2','3,'4','5']
x3= ['test1','test1','test1','test1','test1','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': x1,
                   'ID': x2,
                   'Description': x3
                   })

#define how to aggregate various fields
agg_functions = {'Date': 'first' , 'ID': 'sum' , 'Description': 'first'}

#create new DataFrame by combining rows with same id values
df_new = df.groupby(df['Date']).aggregate(agg_functions)
print(df_new)
```

Output

```
                  Date     ID Description
Date                                     
2023-06-20  2023-06-20  12345        test1
2023-06-23  2023-06-23  12345        test2
```

This is very close to what I would like but I would like the ID section to be a list ['1','2','3,'4','5']

Answer (score 1):

Please see the example below. We can group on both `Date` and `Description` at the same time, and supply a lambda function for `ID` that casts it to a list.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

x1 = ['7/30/2023', '7/30/2023', '7/30/2023', '8/8/2023',
      '8/8/2023', '8/8/2023', '8/8/2023', '8/8/2023',]
x2 = ['76', '77', '78', '76', '77', '78', '76', '77']
x3 = ['Desc. Test 1', 'Desc. Test 1', 'Desc. Test 1' ,
      'Desc. Test 2', 'Desc. Test 2', 'Desc. Test 2',
      'Desc. Test 3', 'Desc. Test 3']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': x1,
                   'ID': x2,
                   'Description': x3
                   })

#the "as_index=False" is optional - prevents Date from becoming the index
df_new = df.groupby(['Date', 'Description'], as_index=False).aggregate({'ID': lambda x: list(x)})


#Rearrange cols if desired
df_new = df_new[['Date', 'ID', 'Description']]
df_new
```